# error in rosdep initialization

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i tried to initialize rosdep,
(xubuntu 14.04 is installed.)

```
sudo rosdep init
```

It gives following error

```
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from: https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list. Website may be down.
```

My proxies are correct. Any idea what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193610/error-in-rosdep-initialization/) by [ama](https://answers.ros.org/users/3049/ama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2016-05-18**:
What do you mean by "My proxies are correct" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo by default does not preserve environment. You need to use the -E option to preserve the environment which is where I presume you're setting up your proxies. Use:

```
sudo -E rosdep init
```

Related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/54150/rosdep-initialization-error/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2